# not able to work with express auth middleware

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

I want to use auth middleware in expressjs with role based auth check or without role based.
after login, i am passing access token as bearer token, but authentication doesn't seems to work.

> **this is auth middleware**

```
const passport = require('passport');
const httpStatus = require('http-status');
const ApiError = require('../utils/ApiError');
const { roleRights } = require('../config/roles');

const verifyCallback = (req, resolve, reject, requiredRights) => async (err, user, info) => {
  if (err || info || !user) {
    return reject(new ApiError(httpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, 'Please authenticate'));
  }
  req.user = user;

  if (requiredRights.length) {
    const userRights = roleRights.get(user.role);
    const hasRequiredRights = requiredRights.every((requiredRight) => userRights.includes(requiredRight));
    if (!hasRequiredRights && req.params.userId !== user.id) {
      return reject(new ApiError(httpStatus.FORBIDDEN, 'Forbidden'));
    }
  }

  resolve();
};

const auth = (...requiredRights) => async (req, res, next) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }, verifyCallback(req, resolve, reject, requiredRights))(req, res, next);
  })
    .then(() => next())
    .catch((err) => next(err));
};

module.exports = auth;
```

> **here in router, i am using middleware like this.**

```
const express = require('express');
const auth = require('../../middlewares/auth');
const validate = require('../../middlewares/validate');
const userValidation = require('../../validations/user.validation');
const userController = require('../../controllers/user.controller');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', auth(), userController.getUsers);


module.exports = router;
```

> **here i am passing accesstoken like this in request**

```
GET http://localhost:5000/v1/users HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer *****************(accesstoken-returned-after-login)************************
```

access token expire time is set to 30 minutes, whenever i pass access token in this request,

> **i am only getting response "Please Authenticate".**

**

> passport.js in config

**

```
    const { Strategy: JwtStrategy, ExtractJwt } = require('passport-jwt');
const config = require('./config');
const { tokenTypes } = require('./tokens');
const { User } = require('../models');

const jwtOptions = {
  secretOrKey: config.jwt.secret,
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
};

const jwtVerify = async (payload, done) => {
  try {
    if (payload.type !== tokenTypes.ACCESS) {
      throw new Error('Invalid token type');
    }
    const user = await User.findById(payload.sub);
    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false);
    }
    done(null, user);
  } catch (error) {
    done(error, false);
  }
};

const jwtStrategy = new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, jwtVerify);

module.exports = {
  jwtStrategy,
};
```

> this is user collection schema

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const { toJSON, paginate } = require('./plugins');
const { roles } = require('../config/roles');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      trim: true,
      lowercase: true,
      validate(value) {
        if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
          throw new Error('Invalid email');
        }
      },
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      minlength: 8,
      validate(value) {
        if (!value.match(/\d/) || !value.match(/[a-zA-Z]/)) {
          throw new Error('Password must contain at least one letter and one number');
        }
      },
      private: true, // used by the toJSON plugin
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      enum: roles,
      default: 'employee',
    },
    isEmailVerified: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);


// add plugin that converts mongoose to json
userSchema.plugin(toJSON);
userSchema.plugin(paginate);

userSchema.statics.isEmailTaken = async function (email, excludeUserId) {
  const user = await this.findOne({ email, _id: { $ne: excludeUserId } });
  return !!user;
};

userSchema.methods.isPasswordMatch = async function (password) {
  const user = this;
  return bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
};

userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  const user = this;
  if (user.isModified('password')) {
    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 8);
  }
  next();
});


const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = {
  User
};
```

Comment: What are the values of err, info or user?

Comment: err prints - TypeError: User.findById is not a function,  and user, info prints undefined.

Comment: Then it looks like there is an error in your user lookup method. Maybe it is something about the database module.

Comment: @ChristianTapia - I updated my question with User Schema.

Comment: I tried to look up for user by passing id using User.findbyId() in services layer and its working fine over there.

Comment: it worked ! model was not getting loaded in passport.js..  i had to change it to - const { User } = require('../models/user.model');

Comment: Great! I guess you can close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had issue in importing collection schema in my passport.js file. i solved it by doing in passport.js

```
const { User } = require('../models/user.model');
```

and everything works as expected.